# Как реализовать повторяющиеся графы в datagridwiew?

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, datagridview

У меня есть datagridwiew, в которую выводятся данные из базы. В таблице всего 3 столбца,то есть она узкая, но при этом очень длинная, там пара сотен записей. Есть ли вариант настроить отображение данных так, чтобы у меня повторялись колонки, но при этом прокрутка вниз не шла, а шла прокрутка вбок? То есть, чтобы было, к примеру: колонка "фио", колонка "зарплата", колонка "дата выдачи"; а потом опять "фио", "зарплата", "дата выдачи" и т.п.